# Is there kosher spreadable whiskey-infused preserves?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, liquor-beer

I am looking for [spreadable whiskey](https://thingsidesire.com/spreadable-whiskey/) that is kosher. I cannot find any sites, be it kosher certification sites or product sites, which even discuss kosher spreadable whiskey. From my search of the product in general I do not see any kosher certification on the packages. I am not aware of any reason this product cannot be kosher. Therefore I would like to know if a mass-produced kosher spreadable whiskey (or gin) exists.

---

**Example of ingredients:** Sugar, Seville Oranges, Malt Whisky (4%), Gelling Agent: Citrus Pectin [this is a plant based substance - OP]. Prepared with 32g of fruit per 100g. Total sugar content 67g per 100g.

---

After some additional digging I found [a site](https://www.tiptree.com/index.php/orange-with-malt-whisky-marmalade.html) which expressly states their version of whiskey marmalade is not certified kosher.

Comment: “...not *certified* kosher.” Predictable :)

Comment: I changed the title to better clarify what this product is. If incorrect, please change it back. Agree with Oliver. Offhand, all the ingredients seem kosher. However, the cooking and processing might be done in non-kosher facilities? This looks like good stuff. Something I'd like to try, perhaps ;-)

Comment: The gelling agent could be a concern; besides that, what is there to worry about except bugs ans bug parts? If the machinery is also used for *stam* grape jelly it's presumably pretty thoroughly cleaned (no manufacturer wants grape flavor in their orange-whisky preserves!)